# FFmpeg parameters for Fisheye image correction

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, 360video

I am trying to achieve two things:

1. Fisheye video to equirectangular
2. Fisheye video to Flat (if I understood correctly, it is a non 360 interactive image. For this I need just the fisheye image but without distortions).

Camera specs: https://documentation.meraki.com/MV/Viewing_Video/Understanding_Image_Quality_on_the_MV32

**For test purposes I am using an image as input**
For 1), I am using `ffmpeg -i input_file -vf v360=fisheye:e:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=90 output_file` This command gives me a rectangular image where the half upper is blank/white, and when testing in https://renderstuff.com/tools/360-panorama-web-viewer/ the user can navigate through this white space (not what I want). If I crop and remove the white part, the image in *renderstuff* becomes distorted.

For 2), I tried `ffmpeg -i input_file -vf v360=fisheye:flat:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180 output_file` but it doesn't seem to correct properly.

FYI this video will be published in AntMedia server to be used as an iframe in web applications.

Comment: Related: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14772/correct-lens-distortion-with-ffmpeg